# Busca via GET não retorna resultados corretamente

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou com um problema com uma busca via GET.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
  //envio o charset para evitar problemas com acentos
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

  include_once ('bd/bd.php');

  $cnpj = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'cnpj');
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `fornecedores` WHERE `cnpj` = '{$cnpj}'"; //monto a query
  $query = $mysqli->query( $sql ); //executo a query

  if( $query->num_rows > 0 ) {//se retornar algum resultado
    echo "Este CNPJ já está cadastrado em nosso banco de dados";
  } else {
    echo "CNPJ OK";
  }

?>
```

Porém quando eu faço uma busca por ex:

> www.site.com/busca-fornec.php?cnpj=85.341.207/0001-82

O resultado deveria ser: "Este CNPJ já está cadastrado em nosso banco de dados", porém está aparecendo "CNPJ OK"

O CNPJ do exemplo está salvo no banco de dados, se eu fizer o SQL diretamente no phpMyAdmin o resultado é encontrado, mostrando que a consulta está ok, porém via GET sempre aparece "CNPJ OK" independente do parametro que eu passar na consulta.

[image: DADOS SALVOS NO BANCO DE DADOS]

Se eu fizer a busca:

> www.site.com/busca-fornec.php?cnpj=123456789

Na teoria deveria dizer que o CNPJ já está cadastrado, correto? Porém aparece que o CNPJ está ok

Comment: Já verificou se a barra presente no valor do CNPJ não está interferindo na URL? Tente codificar o valor antes de enviá-lo pela *query string*.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não interfere, porque coloquei no banco de dados um "CNPJ" no formato 1111111111 e quando eu busco não aparece que o CNPJ ja existe no banco o que deveria acontecer, pois esse cnpj ja esta salvo no banco

Comment: Altere `$query->num_rows` para `$query->num_rows()` e nos retorne o resultado.

Comment: @8biT isso não faz sentido, [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) não é um método.

Comment: @FredericoMoreira Coloque um `var_dump($sql); exit;` antes de executar a query e certifique-se que o valor está chegando corretamente.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss string(59) "SELECT * FROM `fornecedores` WHERE `cnpj` = '123456789'"

Comment: Se eu usar esse select direto no phpMyadmin vai retornar a linha onde existe esse cnpj. Só que no comando via GET fala q nao existe.

Comment: Considerando os acentos graves que foram ocultados no comentário, sua SQL teria 55 caracteres, mas aparece `string(59)`. O que seriam esses outros 4 caracteres?

Comment: Era o nome da tabela que acabei trocando aqui na hra de mandar pra vc. Considere que a string seja string(55)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86070/discussion-between-frederico-moreira-and-anderson-carlos-woss).